# Magento 2: Showing grid in configuration page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grid, configuration

How can I show the grid view of a table in`Magento 2` configuration page?

I have a table of certain data and I need it to show it on the configuration page.

Is there a way to do so?

I want the gird to appear in this red area.

---

[image]

Comment: What exactly mean configuration page?

Comment: store->setting->configuration. 

here i added a new configuration menu. When i clicked on it, it should show me the gird

Comment: I have updated my question please check it again

Comment: I see. Would You like to use similar grid as in Category page with products?

Comment: yes same kind of grid like when a products are listed.

Comment: Why you want to do that when you can create new controller easier

Comment: Client needs i have to do.